# Запрос SQL на Yii

Tags: sql, yii

Пытаюсь сделать запрос к базе

```php
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;

$criteria->condition = 'id IN (SELECT id_todo FROM order WHERE id_user_send = '.Yii::app()->user->id.')';
$this->todos = Todo::model()->findAll('id IN (SELECT id_todo FROM order WHERE id_user_send = '.Yii::app()->user->id.')');
```

Вылетает такая ошибка:

> CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос:
>
> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation:
>
> 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`order WHERE id_user_send = 30)`' at line 1.
>
> The SQL statement executed was:
>
> ```sql
> SELECT *
> FROM `todo` `t` 
> WHERE id IN 
> (
>     SELECT id_todo 
>     FROM order 
>     WHERE id_user_send = 30
> )
> ```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**order WHERE** быть не должно
MYSQL думает, что **order** это **оператор**, а не таблица. Заключите имя в `order`

Answer (score 2):

`ORDER` - это ключевое слово, входящее в выражение `ORDER BY <список условий сортировки>`. Переименуйте таблицу или возьмите ее имя в обратные кавычки:

```
FROM `order`
```